# Why does my first beamer overlay move?

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to create an overlay with some text and `MetaPost` figures and the text from my first overlay jumps when I advance to the next overlay.  I get the same problem using `\onslide` instead of `\visible`.  It also does not seem to matter if I convert my `MetaPost` files to pdf. A simplified version of the slide in question follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\frame{

\visible<1->{Some text.\medskip}

\visible<2->{Some more text.}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics<2>[scale=.8]{figure.mps}
\end{center}
}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome! The image inclusion alters the spacing. Use either the `overprint` or `overlay` environments to prevent this. Beamer's manual has a section devoted to discussing these ways of resolving unwanted 'wobbling'!

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Glad it helped. They are really, really useful environments to know about ;).